# Media Controller hides but media player continues playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediacontroller

I have a media player and associated with it a media controller.The controls are working fine.

I'm getting two issues with it:

1. When the media controller gets focus, i.e. the user touches it and then touches another part of the screen, the media controllers hides though media player continues playing,
2. when I press back, the previous activity launches up, media controller hides but media player continues playing

I have tried the code below, but it crashes the app with the following error. Any suggestion for this?

Code:

```
mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity()){
                            @Override
                            public void hide()
                            {

                                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                                }
                                mediaController.hide();
                            }


                        };
```

Stacktrace when app crashes:

```
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911): Process: com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite, PID: 3911
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911): java.lang.StackOverflowError
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:214)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.ArticleFragment$2$2.hide(ArticleFragment.java:217)
04-09 00:32:49.841: E/AndroidRuntime(3911):     at com.itspirits.lifenavigatorlite.Artic
```

Comment: maybe you should release the mediaPlayer since you called stop().Try release()

Comment: i'm calling release after stop, its still crashing

Answer (score 2):

Try this inside your hide() method:

```
super.hide();
```

Instead of:

```
mediaController.hide();
```

Looks like you had created an eternal loop.

Comment: Agreed, +1.  The mediaController object is being used within its own declaration.